# regex capture includes too much

Tags: java, regex

I have a string from which I would like to caputre all after and including colon until (excluding) white space or paranthesis.

Why does the following regex include the paranthesis in the string match?
`:(.*?)[\(\)\s]` or also `:(.+?)[\)\s]` (non-greedy) does not work.

Example input: `WHERE t.operator_id = :operatorID AND (t.merchant_id = :merchantID) AND t.readerApplication_id = :readerApplicationID AND t.accountType in :accountTypes`

Should exctract `:operatorID`, `:merchantID`, `:readerApplicationID`, `:accountTypes`.
But my regexes extract for the second match `:marchantID)`
What is wrong and why?

Even if I use an exacter mapping condition in the capture, it does not work:
 `:([a-zA-z0-9_]+?)[\)\(\s]`

Comment: `\B(:.*?)(?=[\s\)])` - https://regex101.com/r/FhvOy1/6

Comment: what splash58 is saying is, put your conditional "followed by space or paren" as a *lookahead*, so that it sees but doesn't match.  Right now you are explicitly matching parentheses with `[\(\)\s]`

Comment: you could just use a word boundary also, this is what they're for:  `:(.+?)\b`

Comment: I see, thanks very much. Incredible your quick help!! If someone of you want to earn reputation, make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your conditional "followed by space or paren" as a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so that it sees but doesn't match. Right now you are explicitly matching parentheses with `[\(\)\s]`:

```
:(.+?)(?=[\s\(\)])
```

https://regex101.com/r/im8KWF/1/

Or, use the built-in `\b` "[word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)", which is also a "zero-width" assertion meaning the same thing*:

```
:(.+?)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/FnnzGM/3/

*Definition of word boundary from regular-expressions.info:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>   word character. After the last character in the string, if the last
>   character is a word character. Between two characters in the string,
>   where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.